# Conformal Killing Group volume in string amplitude calculations

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, vector-fields

In string amplitude calculations, the volume conformal Killing group (CKG), if finite, can enter into the calculations when the number of external vertex operator insertions is less than the (complex) dimension of the conformal Killing group.

I have the following question on the calculation of CKG volume on a flat torus with a modulus $\tau=\tau_1+i\tau_2$. I know, from textbooks, that there are two (inconsistent?) ways. First, let us define the torus as
\begin{eqnarray}
\xi^1\sim\xi^1+1;\xi^2\sim\xi^2+1,
\end{eqnarray}
with the metric (or distance element more precisely) as
\begin{eqnarray}
ds^2=|d\xi^1+\tau d\xi^2|=g_{ij}d\xi^id\xi^j.
\end{eqnarray}

1. The calculation from "Blumenhagen: Basic Concepts in String Theory"

The CKG is generated by two global vector fields $\partial_{\xi^1}$ and $\partial_{\xi^2}$ thereby any conformal Killing vector field being
\begin{eqnarray}
a^1\partial_{\xi^1}+a^2\partial_{\xi^2},
\end{eqnarray}
with $a^1\sim a^1+1$ and $a^2\sim a^2+1$ due to the periodicity of the torus (actually I don't understand why the periodicity of the torus could imply this periodicity?)

To properly renormalize the volume, the induced metric on the CKG is calculated as
\begin{eqnarray}
h_{ij}\equiv\langle\partial_{\xi^i},\partial_{\xi^j}\rangle\equiv\int d\xi^1 d\xi^2\sqrt{g}g_{\alpha\beta}\delta^\alpha_i\delta^\beta_j.
\end{eqnarray}
Then the volume of CKG follows as
\begin{eqnarray}
V_\text{CKG}=\int_0^1 da^1\int_0^1da^2\sqrt{h}={\tau_2^2}.
\end{eqnarray}

2. A direct observation:
   Let us first restrict to the case of $\tau_1=0$ or $\tau=i\tau_2$. We could also directly see that CKG is isomorphic to U$(1)\times$U$(1)$ generated by two orthogonal translations. Since the lengths of two cycles are $1$ and $\tau_2$, we can read that the volume of the group as
   \begin{eqnarray}
   V_\text{CKG}'=\tau_2.
   \end{eqnarray}

My first question is which one is the correct one. [The second minor question is, in the former approach, why the periodicity of the torus could imply the periodicity of the vector fields.]